# QMenuBar is missing or invisible on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I have a Qt4 application which builds and runs correctly on Windows. However when I build and run it on Linux (ubuntu 12.04), the QMenuBar of my main window (QMainWindow) is missing. The space it takes appears to be allocated but its invisible/transparent.

Answer (score 0):

try to set it manually

mainLayout->setMenuBar(menubar);

It worked for me.